# I need a netspeed indicator for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, networking, monitor, applet

I have a 3G mobile broadband connection that keeps changing network speed according to location and time and so I relied heavily on this applet http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-display-network-upload-download.html to monitor my netspeed and to choose a good location and time to download big files.

Now this applet doesn't seem to run on Ubuntu 14.04 anymore. I love this release and I don't want to relapse into previous releases for this. So I need an alternative to this one that displays netspeed in digits unlike indicator multiload! Any help would be appreciated.

I found this applet here  https://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed and I added it to startup applications like this:

```
cd indicator-netspeed && make && ./indicator-netspeed
```

but it does not start and so i created a file with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd indicator-netspeed && make && ./indicator-netspeed
```

and added it to startup applications. Now it runs perfectly but it shows only download speed!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Command-Line Speed Test Utility on GitHub](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) that tests both the upload and download speeds.  You'd want to check the link for the correct checksums, but here's what I did:

```
wget -O speedtest-cli https://raw.github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest_cli.py
chmod +x speedtest-cli
sha256sum speedtest-cli
```

You can list available servers using `./speedtest-cli --list`, or you can just run it with no options to let it determine the best server to use.

Answer (score 0):

I created this one some months ago:
https://github.com/dmisdani/netspeed_indicator

It is an indicator applet to monitor the system network speed and also the network speed per process and per device.

**Latest Deb:** [netspeed-indicator_1.0.1_amd64.deb](https://github.com/dmisdani/netspeed_indicator/blob/master/deploy/netspeed-indicator_1.0.1_amd64.deb)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I cannot succeed to make that works : netspeed-indicator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/netspeed-indicator/netspeed-indicator2.py", line 15, in <module>
    import appindicator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appindicator/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _appindicator import *
ImportError: could not import gobject (could not find _PyGObject_API object)